# Webpack 5 React component library UMD bundle with SourceMaps

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, webpack, umd

I am attempting to make a webpack 5 build process to create a react component library I just had a couple of things cannot seem to get working.

**#1)** The webpack build command works fine, and when using the inline-source-map option I can
SEE the data URL embeded in the outputted build file  but when I ever I attempt to publish and test this library on NPM I always get obfuscated errors without original lines of code so I can't even tell where the errors are; what else am I missing to activate source-maps? I am using Chrome dev tools and it doesn't even tell me a source map is available for that code...

**#2)** Another issue I am having is after building this with webpack into the dist folder; I start another CRA test app and try to pull components out of the built library but all I get are these errors.

```
./src/dist/index.js
  Line 1:1:    Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression  no-unused-expressions
  Line 1:112:  'define' is not defined                                                no-undef
  Line 1:123:  'define' is not defined                                                no-undef
  Line 1:190:  Unexpected use of 'self'                                               no-restricted-globals
  Line 1:466:  Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression  no-unused-expressions
  Line 1:631:  Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression  no-unused-expressions
```

I am aware webpack 5 stopped bundling polyfills for Node but shouldn't this code run
if I place it in the src directory of a CRA application?  This is bundled code shouldn't it work in the browser/ in another React application? I targeted UMD so I thought it would work in this environment

here is all the necessary info

Webpack.config.js

```
    const path = require("path");
    const { CleanWebpackPlugin } = require("clean-webpack-plugin");
    const nodeExternals = require("webpack-node-externals");
    module.exports = {
      entry: "./src/index.js",
      devtool: "inline-source-map",
      externals: [nodeExternals()],
      output: {
        filename: "index.js",
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, "dist"),
        library: {
          name: "test",
          type: "umd",
        },
      },
      plugins: [new CleanWebpackPlugin()],
      module: {
        rules: [
          {
            test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
            exclude: /node_modules/,
            use: {
              loader: "babel-loader",
              options: {
                presets: ["@babel/preset-env", "@babel/preset-react"],
              },
            },
          },

          {
            test: /\.scss$/,
            use: ["style-loader", "css-loader", "sass-loader"],
            include: path.resolve(__dirname, "./src"),
          },
        ],
      },
    };
```

Package.json

```
    {
      "name": "test-lib",
      "version": "1.0.0",
      "description": "",
      "main": "index.js",
      "scripts": {
        "start": "start-storybook",
        "build": "webpack --mode production"
      },
      "keywords": [],
      "author": "",
      "license": "ISC",
      "dependencies": {
        "prop-types": "^15.7.2",
        "react": "^17.0.2",
        "react-dom": "^17.0.2"
      },
      "devDependencies": {
        "@babel/core": "^7.15.8",
        "@babel/preset-env": "^7.15.8",
        "@babel/preset-react": "^7.14.5",
        "@storybook/addon-knobs": "^6.3.1",
        "@storybook/react": "^6.3.10",
        "babel-loader": "^8.2.2",
        "clean-webpack-plugin": "^4.0.0",
        "node-sass": "^6.0.1",
        "path": "^0.12.7",
        "sass-loader": "^12.1.0",
        "webpack": "^5.58.0",
        "webpack-cli": "^4.9.0",
        "webpack-node-externals": "^3.0.0"
      }
    }
```

Button.js (sample component)

```
import React from 'react'
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
const Button = ({message = 'Hello world'}) => (
   <button>{message}</button>
)

Button.propTypes = {
    message: PropTypes.string.isRequired
}
export default Button
```

Build entry point (index.js)

```
export { default as Button } from "./components/Button";
```

Comment: Any update on this and whether you were able to get it working? I'm currently bundling my component library using Rollup that makes it relatively simple and there are ton similar questions and solutions out there... however I'm now inclined to jump over to Webpack 5 and see if I could achieve the same result and reduce my bundle size by any chance.